# Throw new MongooseError(‘Model.find() no longer accepts a callback’);

Tags: mongoose

```
    throw new MongooseError('Model.find() no longer accepts a callback');
    ^

MongooseError: Model.find() no longer accepts a callback
    at Function.find (D:\programming\programs\.vscode\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2081:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\programming\programs\.vscode\FruitsProject\mongoose.js:37:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

Node.js v18.16.1

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/fruitsDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: {

        type: String,

        required: [true, "Please check your data entry, no name specified!"]

    },

    rating: {

        type: Number,

        min: 1,

        max: 6

    },

    review: String

});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: String,

    age: Number

});

const Person = mongoose.model("Person", personSchema);

async function saveFruitAndPerson() {

    try {

        // Creating and saving a Fruit document

        const fruit = new Fruit({

            name: "Grapes",

            rating: 6,

            review: "Grape is a good fruit"

        });

        const savedFruit = await fruit.save();

        console.log("Saved fruit:", savedFruit);

        // Creating and saving a Person document

        const person = new Person({

            name: "John",

            age: 37

        });

        const savedPerson = await person.save();

        console.log("Saved person:", savedPerson);

        // Using findOne to retrieve a Fruit document

        const retrievedFruit = await Fruit.findOne({ name: "Grapes" });

        console.log("Retrieved fruit:", retrievedFruit);

        // Using findOne to retrieve a Person document

        const retrievedPerson = await Person.findOne({ name: "John" });

        console.log("Retrieved person:", retrievedPerson);

    } catch (error) {

        console.error("Error:", error);

    } finally {

        mongoose.connection.close(); // Close the database connection

    }

}

saveFruitAndPerson();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case: I changed mongoose version in package.json from mongoose": "^7.4.3" to "mongoose": "5.13.20". And then, reinstall node modules.